# Perl6: how do I read mixed parameters from the command line?

Tags: raku

I run programs all the time from the command line that allow your to mix the order of the parameters. And they catch you if you throw something extra into the mix.  For example:

```
$xxx -r abc  -q def  -w xyz

$xxx -w xyz  -q def  -r abc
```

How are they doing this?  Is there some module for this?

Comment: See e.g. [Getopt::Long](https://modules.raku.org/dist/Getopt::Long:cpan:LEONT)

Answer (score 9):

Here is an example using [Getopt::Long](https://modules.raku.org/dist/Getopt::Long:cpan:LEONT):

```
use v6;
use Getopt::Long;

my %opt = help => False, 'r=s' => "", 'q=s' => "", 'w=s' => "";
my %options = get-options(%opt).hash;
say %options;
say @*ARGS;
```

Example run:

```
$ p.p6  -w xyz -q def -r abc hello
{help => False, q => def, r => abc, w => xyz}
[hello]
```

Comment: @Todd All arguments that are processed as options are removed from `@*ARGS` by `get-options()`. So non-options arguments are left in `@*ARGS` afterwards. See updated answer

Comment: It sets `help` to a default value of 0. Probably it would be better to use a boolean: `help => False` since the help option is typically used to show a help message. I have edited the answer such that `help` is a boolean.

Answer (score 8):

Use the [`MAIN` sub](https://docs.raku.org/routine/MAIN):

```
#!/usr/bin/env raku

use v6;

sub MAIN(:$these ="These", :$are="Are", :$params="Params") {
    say "$these $are $params";
}
```

You can type these parameters in any order:

```
./command-line.p6 --are=well --these=those
those well Params
```

And will also catch any extra parameter, showing you the actual parameters:

```
./command-line.p6 --are=well --these=those --not=this_one
Usage:
  ./command-line.p6 [--these=<Any>] [--are=<Any>] [--params=<Any>]
```

If you are only interested in parameters with a single dash, [you'll need GetOpt::Long as indicated by Hakon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59114152/891440)